# How to create an exe file with gcc

Tags: linux, windows, gcc, mingw, executable

I use gcc in Linux and I have a program written in C.
I builded a Linux executable with this source code, and I know that I use gcc in Windows (MinGw), I can create an exe file.
But is there a way to do it using gcc in Linux?
Thanks.

Comment: You can see detail steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48422547/9118583

Answer (score 1):

To build a Windows executable you need a MinGW version of the GCC compiler.

As you know there are MinGW compilers for Windows, but there are also MinGW compilers on Linux allowing you to cross-compile for Windows on Linux. Search your Linux package repository (apt, yum, ...) for MinGW...